How to find the least number of 0s using IVT"


So after identifying there's a tmoat 3 zeros of this function we need to use the IVT to show that there are at least 3 zeros for this function. But look at this thing… how do we even possibly begin? How do you get a sense of where the 0s should generally be, and then choose the appropriate 4 points that go from negative to positive to negative to positive? I tried but could not find them and had to desmos it in the end! Does anyone know a legit way actually to find the intermediate intervals for this gruesome function? Thanks in advance!

This is hard to follow.  It looks like you are jumbling together several unconnected problems.  You give two seemingly unrelated definitions of $f(x)$.  Which one did you mean, if either?  What do the roots of $f(x)$ have to do with the max and min?  I suggest editing the post completely.

New Year’s resolution: Spend more time proofreading questions I’m asking others to help me with.
